# Oracle 11g SOA Suite Database adapter accepting list as input

Tags: web-services, soa, jdeveloper

I would like to be able to create a service with Oracle 11g SOA Suite Database Adapter that takes a list as input. So I would like to be able to feed the getCountries operation a list of countryId.

I found [this](http://soa-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-use-sql-query-having-in-clause.html) link. It works but it breaks on a parameter that contains the delimiting character so  it's not ideal.

I've been trying to use a function that has a collection as input and as output and use for-each constructs to do the mapping. But can't get it to work. I'm not certain if DBAdapeter can handle this.

Has anybody tried something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that - make that Parameter (`pCountryList`) a string.

To make it work you need to supply the list as a valid XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Countries>
<Country><ID>MyCountyID 01</ID></Country>
<Country><ID>777</ID></Country>
<Country><ID>ID__3</ID></Country>
</Countries>
```

Then you need to create a query with a subselect that transforms the XML into rows (each row containing one country ID from the XML)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CountryID IN
(
SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/Country/ID') ContryID
FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE(:pCountryList).extract('/Countries/Country'))) t);
```

This query takes a list of country IDs (packaged into an XML string) and can be used with *Oracle 11g SOA Suite Database Adapter*.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible way when giving parameter as **delimited string** for example:

where #parameter is simple delimited String: "'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'"

SELECT U.A, U.B  FROM C U  WHERE U.A in ( SELECT SUBSTR ( STRING_TO_TOKENIZE , DECODE(LEVEL, 1, 1, INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL-1)+1) , INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL) - DECODE(LEVEL, 1, 1, INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL-1)+1) ) FROM ( SELECT #parameter || ',' AS STRING_TO_TOKENIZE , ',' AS DELIMITER FROM DUAL ) CONNECT BY INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL)>0 )

The trick is in the following sub-query as it returns parsed rows from delimited string:

SELECT SUBSTR ( STRING_TO_TOKENIZE , DECODE(LEVEL, 1, 1, INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL-1)+1) , 
INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL) - DECODE(LEVEL, 1, 1, INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL-1)+1) ) FROM 
( SELECT '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' || ',' AS STRING_TO_TOKENIZE , ',' AS DELIMITER FROM DUAL ) CONNECT BY INSTR(STRING_TO_TOKENIZE, DELIMITER, 1, LEVEL)>0